# Changed upload_max_filesize in php.ini but phpinfo doesn't show the change

Tags: mamp, php

Basically phpinfo says upload_max_filesize is 2M, but I changed it in the php.ini file to 8M.  I am using MAMP, so I restarted MAMP and phpinfo still says 2M.  I checked the path to the php.ini file that phpinfo shows and it matched up exactly.  See the YouTube video of me documenting all of this.

Comment: Try searching php.ini for the string "upload_max_filesize".  Seeing as how you were just scrolling line by line it is possible that it is set again below.  "grep upload_max_filesize /path/to/php.ini"

Comment: @davidcroda - I just did a search and it only appears once in the php.ini file.

Comment: @Amir are there any local overrides? Sometimes it's set up so that .htaccess and other folder-specific files can change those global values.

Comment: @Ansari those should be listed in his phpinfo though.

Comment: I solved it!  See Answer below!  Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: You can update PHP configurations from File(menu) -> Open template -> PHP -> {select PHP version that you want update}
http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In httpd.conf file the PhpIniDir had the wrong path.  It was off by one directory.  That was the fix!

Answer (score 13):

You should change the file in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini

After you should reset MAMP. I also changed all php.ini before, and phpinfo() doesn't had been change, but I don't sure if it is need to works, so if only changing the file in the path above, try change the others also.

I hope that help you.

Comment: Helpful for me. For Windows, the php.ini located at: C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.12 (you may need to update 5.5.12 according the php verion you've used.)

Answer (score 6):

On **MAC** os make sure you are at the right `path`:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/phpx.x.x/conf/php.ini`

I see a lot of people had trouble with this since there is also another conf directory

Comment: Thank you. I was changing in MAMP/conf instead of bin. Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

To be sure, write a file with this PHP content:

```
<?php

phpInfo();

?>
```

and save it in your main MAMP document root (as any other web page) with name `info.php`

Open that file as a web URL in your browser as any other MAMP web page, as an example: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/info.php`

Search for the string: `php.ini` in that page.

You will find a line like this:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf`

That line will show you the correct path for the ini file PHP is using in that moment. It depends on the PHP version you are using.

Delete (or rename with an unguessable name) the info.php file, after (avoid giving all this info to the world).

Answer (score 3):

You can update PHP configurations using below:

```
File(menu) -> Open template -> PHP -> {select PHP version that you want update}
```

Source: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html

Comment: If I could upvote you 3 times, I would. It was the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

MAMP PRO php config file is loaded from other path.

I found it after replace all php infos from mamp/bin/php/ directory without results.

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/php(VERSION).ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with MAMP (non pro), MAM is stopped
the current php version I am using is php7.2.20, I have changed everywhere  in 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.20 and /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.2.20

post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M

I restart MAMP and I get php7.2.20
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 32M