# PHP POST Content-Length warning

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I set both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to `128M` in my php.ini file, restarted MAMP but it did not work. In my phpinfo() it says that `upload_max_filesize` is set to `32M` and so is `post_max_size`. Why would this be happening? I made sure that I'm editing the correct php.ini and restarting everything accordingly. Any help would be great. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I know you said you've made sure about correct php.ini, but I'll ask it anyway. Does `phpinfo()` shows in row `Loaded Configuration File ` the path that you're assuming as correct php.ini's path?

Comment: @devpro Did that multiple times and even updated the Loaded Configuration File in the php.ini. Nothing seems to change it from 32M

Comment: @dragoste The loaded file is different from the one I'm changing but even when updating the loaded one it does not change anything. It sticks at 32M

Comment: Here's similar issue. Maybe it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638868/changed-upload-max-filesize-in-php-ini-but-phpinfo-doesnt-show-the-change

Comment: @dragoste I tried this solution already and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MAMP Pro, you need to edit your php.ini file in the MAMP menu under `File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP x.xx php.ini`

The problem is that MAMP Pro dynamically generates the php.ini on every start and therefore overwrites your manually edited file.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you very much.