# how to access php.ini in MAMP

Tags: sql, mamp

I am trying to increase the file upload size for phpMyAdmin so I can import a SQL database.

In order to do so I need to edit `php.ini`. However, I can't find it on my computer. I am using MAMP on a Win 10 machine.  Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: This answer would help too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856119/4819200

You can update PHP.ini from `File(menu) -> Open template -> PHP -> {select PHP version that you want update}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find php.ini in

`C:\MAMP\conf\`

Answer (score 0):

On my mac, running MAMP I have a few locations that would be the likely php.ini,
so I edited the memory_limit to different values in the 2 suspected files,
to test which one effected the actual MAMP PHP INFO page details.
By doing that I was able to determine that this was the correct php.ini:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini

Assuming MAMP uses same directory structure on PC, then it would just be the php(number) that would differ depending on what PHP is set in your MAMP Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP keep its php.ini in the following location.

```
/Aplications/MAMP/conf/bin/php/**{current php version}**/conf/php.ini
```

Ex: `/Aplications/MAMP/conf/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini`